# Build schedule in Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I am working on a POC currently using Jenkins as CI server. I have setup jobs based on certain lifecycle stages such as test suite and QA. I have configured these jobs to become scheduled builds based on a cron expression.

I have a request to know how to find out what the next scheduled build will be in Jenkins based on the jobs i have created. I know what was the last succesful build, the last failed but i dont know the next proposed build. Any clues!? Or is there a view plugin for this? Sorry if this is a strange request but i need to find out.

Also i need to discover if there is an issue when more than one job is running concurrently what will happen. I would have understood this is not an issue. I do not have any slaves setup, i only have the master.

Jenkins version: 1.441

I found the first issue!

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Executions

So can you help me on the second question please? Is there any issue with more than one job building concurrently?

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the next execution date take a look at Next Execution Plugin [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Executions).

For your second question .
The number of build you can run concurrently is configurable in the jenkins server params(http:///configure : executors param).
If the number of executor is reached each new job triggered will be add in jenkins's execution queue and will be run when one running job will end

Comment: Cheers mate i just went through all available plugins and found it! How do i know how many executors i should use?

Comment: The number of executors is related to configuration of your jenkins server.Sort your projects according machine resources they use and see how many of the biggest you can do concurrently.Or you can do it begin with and arbitrary number and adapt it as soon as you have an issue

Comment: Thanks mate, thats all i needed to know.

Comment: @shanelee *"How many executors?"* Rule of thumb I use is *at most one executor per CPU per node*.  Quick Google search showed some [similar advice](http://soldering-iron.blogspot.com/2014/01/jenkins-performance-hints.html).